# React-Native-Navigation Disable upside-down orientation

Tags: android-manifest, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using react native navigation for navigation on both iOS and Android. How can I set it such that every other orientation is supported except for upside-down?

[Here is a link](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/styling-the-navigator) to the documentation but it seems like it only supports specifying portrait or landscape, nothing specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify the supported device orientations in XCode and Android Studio.

In XCode this is easy: you just selected which orientations you want to support in the general project settings. There are 4 checkboxes for all orientations.

For Android this can be done in the AndroidManifest.xml file, where you can configure the android:screenOrientation property in the activity section.

Comment: When using react-native-orientation the entries in android manifest file are not respected. I have tried doing it on Android at least. Didnt work

Comment: Okay didn't know about that. But it should definitely work in XCode though.